# How log in oracle database as administrator, if my user account is locked

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have one user in my database, and he is locked. I want to unlock account, but for this I must log in as administrator, when I input in command prompt:
sqlplus "/as sysdba" I got the error ORA 01031: insufficient privileges. Say me please, how I can unlock my account..

Comment: Well, login as SYS or SYSTEM account - `sqlplus sys as sysdba`. You still need to know SYS or SYSTEM password, though. If you don't know, then ask your DB administrator.

Answer (score 2):

If you've forgotten all your passwords (!?!?) You won't be able to do this remotely. Log on to the database server with an account that is a member of the OS 'dba' group ('ora_dba' on Windows). This will be the OS account used to install Oracle. Then you should be able to 'sqlplus / as sysdba'. That will connect you as 'sys', using OS authentication.  The 'ora-1031' indicates you are trying to connect remotely with a password.